# Why tensorflow constant is feedable true

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.VERSION)

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3])
b = tf.constant([2, 2, 2], tf.float32)
c = a + b
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(tf.get_default_graph().is_feedable(b))
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: [3, 2, 3]}))
```

The output of this is the below

```
1.0.1
True
[ 5.  4.  5.]
```

I don't understand why is tensorflow saying that the constant is feedable. Placeholder is feedable true but why constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in TF you can also [feed values in constants and variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data):

> While you can replace any Tensor with feed data, including variables and constants, the best practice is to use a tf.placeholder node

Check it for yourself:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([2, 2, 2], tf.float32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(a, feed_dict={a: [3, 2, 3]}))
```

Constant `a` changed its value.